# Can CNN be used with 3d dataset

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, keras

My dataset is a simple table of 20 columns and 100,000 rows.It is not a image data as commonly used in CNN. What input shape should I provide in this case?

Right now I did-

```
input_shape = (21,109713,1)

model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(1, 1),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
```

which gives the error-

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (109713, 19)
```

Answer (score 2):

The question in the title is inconsistent with the question body. If you are intent on using a CNN albeit it not being the best idea for this type of data, then for the dataset you are describing a 1D CNN architecture would be most suitable.

To answer the question in the title, yes a 3D CNN is definitely possible and is actually commonly used on 3D data, for example: video (3rd dimension is time), 3D medical images, etc.

The instances in the dataset you described is a vector with 20 instances. This data is a single dimensional structure. You can thus use a 1D CNN as described [here](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/).

However, it would be best to use a DNN for such a data structure. As a CNN is essentially cross-correlation of neighboring features. In this case, your data cannot be assumed to have such similarities between adjacent features. A DNN will allow for cross-correlation between distant features to be captured more effectively.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to JahKnows's answer, if your data represents progression in time, using a 1D-CNN might be a good idea (but perhaps you might also consider an RNN), otherwise you should probably stick with a DNN.